# pandas faster way than apply lambda to apply a logic in each row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a df:

```
dfs = """
    contract Valindex0  RB  Valindex1
2   A00118  51  0   50
3   A00118  42  1   47
4   A00118  44  1   47

"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dfs.strip()), sep='\s+')
```

df:

```
  contract  Valindex0  RB  Valindex1
2   A00118         51   0         50
3   A00118         42   1         47
4   A00118         44   1         47
```

I want to add a new column to each row df['Valindex'],

this column value is either

```
 df['Valindex0']
```

or

```
 df['Valindex1']
```

it depends on the df['RB']:

```
if df['RB']==0:
   df['Valindex'] = df['Valindex0']
elif df['RB']==1:
  df['Valindex'] = df['Valindex1']
```

Now I'm using apply lambda,but it is very slow:

```
df['Valindex'] = df.apply(
    lambda df: df["Valindex" + str(df["RB"])], axis=1)
```

The output should looks like:

```
    contract    Valindex0   RB  Valindex1   Valindex
2   A00118            51    0   50          51
3   A00118            42    1   47          47
4   A00118            44    1   47          47
```

Any faster way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df["Valindex"] = np.where(df["RB"].eq(0), df["Valindex0"], df["Valindex1"])
```

OR

use [`np.select()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for multiple cases and conditions:

```
conditions = [df["RB"].eq(0), df["RB"].eq(1)]
labels = [df["Valindex0"], df["Valindex1"]]
df["Valindex"] = np.select(conditions, labels)
```

output of `df`:

```
    contract    Valindex0   RB  Valindex1   Valindex
2   A00118      51          0   50          51
3   A00118      42          1   47          47
4   A00118      44          1   47          47
```

Comment: Edited your answer to add links to mentioned functions. Feel free to revert changes if not okay.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html).

```
df["Valindex"] = df["Valindex0"].where(df["RB"].eq(0), df["Valindex1"])


  contract  Valindex0  RB  Valindex1  Valindex
2   A00118         51   0         50        51
3   A00118         42   1         47        47
4   A00118         44   1         47        47
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us jus try assign

```
df['Valindex'] = df['Valindex0']

df.loc[df.RB==1,'Valindex'] = df['Valindex1']
```

Answer (score 2):

Running a bunch of methods and timing each method on 1000 rows, it seems Method 3 as suggested by Anurag works best. The timing varies each run, but the ranking doesn't change.

```
#Method 1 (original) - 0.0168s
df['Valindex'] = df.apply(lambda df: df["Valindex" + str(df["RB"])], axis=1)

#Method 2 - 0.0015s
df['Valindex'] = (df['RB'] == 0 ) * df['Valindex0'] + df['RB'] * df['Valindex1']

#Method 3 - 0.0009s
df["Valindex"] = np.where(df["RB"].eq(0), df["Valindex0"], df["Valindex1"])

#Method 4 - 0.0014s
df["Valindex"] = df["Valindex0"].where(df["RB"].eq(0), df["Valindex1"])

#Method 5 - 0.0022s
df['Valindex'] = df['Valindex0']
df.loc[df.RB==1,'Valindex'] = df['Valindex1']
```